# Grails where-query using joda-time

Tags: grails, jodatime

We are using Grails 2.3.11 with the joda-time plugin 1.4.

I was trying to use a where query like this:

```
Form.where { year(dateCreated) == currYear }.list()
```

In this `currYear` is an integer and `dateCreated` is of type `org.joda.time.DateTime`

The result is this Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unsupported function [year] defined in query for property [datum] with type [class org.joda.time.DateTime]
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.applyDetachedCriteria(DynamicFinder.java:440)
    at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.withPopulatedQuery_closure10(DetachedCriteria.groovy:1201)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withDatastoreSession_closure23(GormStaticApi.groovy:699)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.AbstractDatastoreApi.execute(AbstractDatastoreApi.groovy:37)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withDatastoreSession(GormStaticApi.groovy:698)
    at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.withPopulatedQuery(DetachedCriteria.groovy:1185)
    at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.list(DetachedCriteria.groovy:845)
    at grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.list(DetachedCriteria.groovy:844)
```

It seems that functions like year() are not supported when using joda-time.
Is this correct?
Or am I doing something wrong?

How hard would it be at add support for this in the joda-time plugin?
Or somewhere else?

Comment: It's probably not a problem of Joda Datetime but that underlaying database doesn't support year function.

Comment: When I change the `dateCreated` to a `java.util.Date` it works correctly.

Comment: And do you have dateCreated mapped to a proper persistent type when using DateTime? static mapping = { dateCreated type: PersistentDateTime }

Comment: We have the mapping in our `Config.groovy`: // Added by the Joda-Time plugin:
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
 "user-type" type: org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime, class: org.joda.time.DateTime
}

Comment: I'm having a similar issue trying to do, e.g., `Form.where { dateCreated.toLocalDate() == currDate }.list()`.  I think the problem is that the contents of a Criteria block is a DSL, not straight groovy.  Not sure how to deal with that :/